# How can we make webforms in asp.net without using viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

i need to make a large website , but when using web forms in asp.net , we have viewstate issues.As viewstate makes site very heavy.
Do we have any alternative for this, i do not want to use mvc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewState can be disabled using [EnableViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx)="false" (or [ViewStateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx)="disabled") attribute at Web Application, page or web control level and viewstate data will not be stored in HTML.

You can save your data in [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) (Unique for each user) or [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972379.aspx) (Same for all users)

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

Save data into session:

```
Session["YourKeyName"] = "Object data";
```

Get saved data from session:

```
object o = Session["YourKeyName"] as object; // Where object can be any type
```

Save data into Cache:

```
Cache["YourAnotherKeyName"] = "Object data";
```

Get saved data from Cache:

```
object o = Cache["YourAnotherKeyName"] as object; // Where object can be any type
```

Comment: okay , when my session is heavy,will it effect while navigating other pages...or do it will have any impact

Comment: Sessions, by default, are stored on server side (in memory). So reading and writing are very fast.

Comment: sessions are stored on client side or server side , what about cache...which side

Comment: Please read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net and this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29899/Exploring-Caching-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 1):

There are several "fixes" here.

1. Store viewstate in session.  Personally, I don't like this, but that's mainly because I don't like using session for anything.
2. Split viewstate across multiple hidden form fields.  Out of the box it's stored in one gigantic field.  This is handled in your web.config by setting the [maxPageStateFieldLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maxpagestatefieldlength.aspx) to something reasonable like 1024.
3. Go through your pages and fix those that are heavy on viewstate.  The biggest offenders are grids and other repeating views, especially if you are using the built in paging functions.  Basically, get rid of the various standard .net controls and replace them with controls that don't try to send entire data sets to the client.
4. Disable viewstate altogether.  Although I like this, it's not often achievable.  Especially if you are using controls that absolutely depend on it (like grids with the built in paging..).

The fastest "fix" is number 2 above.  That will allow you to get past issues with certain safari versions.  Essentially, your biggest problem is that various browsers have limits on the amount of data that can appear in a single form field.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix you can store the viewstate in the session very easily. There are hundreds of how-to articles on the subject.

But in the long run it is to your benefit to learn how to use the viewstate more efficiently.

Comment: aren't there any very good option..i mean how in mvc they are able to get rid of viewstate...

Comment: http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2006/12/09/Move-the-ViewState-to-Session-and-eliminate-page-bloat.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use ViewState but want to mantain state of your controls you can use the Session or manually assigning values to your controls after each post to the server. You can always disable ViewState for the heavier controls, and enable it for the least heavy ones.

Good luck!